# Browser triggered reload inside SPA with angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an angular SPA being served by node, but whenever I refresh / reload a non root page, the express based server intercepts the route and returns "cannot GET route_X". What functionality is missing from my routes to enable this refresh behavior?

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/nests.html',
        controller: 'NestController'

    .when('/pair/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/pairing.html',
        controller: 'PairController'
    })

    .when('/pairs', {
        templateUrl: 'views/pairs.html',
        controller: 'PairListController'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }
]);
```

The only route I have defined in my express server is as follows...

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var html = fs.readFileSync('public/views/index.html', 'utf8');
  res.send(html);
});
```

with all other routing functionality living in the index file.

Comment: what do your links look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to route all requests (expect your static ones) to index.html:

```
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/public/js"));
...

app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
  var html = fs.readFileSync('public/views/index.html', 'utf8');
  res.send(html);
});
```

Comment: Like a charm. Did you find this in the docs or just know about it from past experience?

Comment: I did some AngularJS projects in the past, so mainly from experience. BTW a nice resource for this type of stack is http://mean.io